# Swift, SpriteKit. Changing Texture Atlas Format in "Build Settings > Texture Atlas Settings" has no effect on memory usage

Tags: swift, format, sprite, atlas

I'm trying to change the Texture Atlas Format in "**Build Settings > Texture Atlas Settings**" from **RGBA8888** to **RGBA4444**, but the memory usage in both cases stays the same.

I tried to do that with normal png textures with **RGBA8888** format and with textures from the TexturePacker with **RGBA4444** format but still, the textures use the same amount of memory and it doesn't matter which format i choose (**RGBA8888_PNG, RGBA8888_COMPRESSED, RGBA565_COMPRESSED** etc.).

Please tell what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about memory, but I once read an article that theses settings affect how fast it loads into memory. You could try to actually compress the big image with an online compressor like compresspng.com

Comment: i think this png/jpg/image compressor is better way2enjoy.com/compress-png as it allows 50 files in one chance. plugin is not recommended as it will always keep your server loaded with excess load. i agree that it will automate the process but when you can do samething in 1 second through online without slowing down your website then i think that is the best. if you know any better then kindly share link.
Get rid of Plugin and make super fast website.